# extreme programming SaaS collaborative tools

Tags: extreme-programming, collaborative

I'm looking for SaaS collaborative tools dedicated to extreme programming. Something like SocialText with back log, task and project management, dashboard, etc...
Which tools are you using ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Trello](http://www.Trello.com).
We have been using it for a while and it is great.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [google wave](https://wave.google.com) which is simple as possible. You can add google gadgets like spreadsheet, calendar, dashboard etc. to your wave. You can add images, attechments. You can manage project collaboratively in wave.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/)? It has a backlog, a ticketing system for user stories, hosted source control for GIT and SVN and a Wiki for documenting requirements. It also shows the usual burndown charts etc.

Answer (score -1):

3 great tools I love:

1. [Xplanner](http://www.xplanner.org/) or [XPlanner+](http://xplanner-plus.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com)
3. [Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/mingle-agile-project-management)

Not all of them are essentially SaaS, but it's easy to install and start using all of them

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) if you are following iterations. If you are doing more like Kanban Style, I would recommend [Trello](https://trello.com/) both are SaaS solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Extreme Programming is, in its turn, described as concentrating on the test-driven approach. Its principles are, basically, best engineering practices taken to the extreme (hence the name "Extreme Programming"). XP is often said to equal pair programming; however, it is not completely true. While XP does include this practice, it consists of 11 more practices, including writing unit tests first, continuous integration, etc.

A quick side note: if you decide to use the XP framework, make sure you follow all 12 guidelines - omitting even one of them may make the whole process inefficient.[link to full source](https://jelvix.com/blog/scrum-extreme-programming-difference)